# Linq to select list of items from custom nested list of objects

Tags: c#, linq

I have created following object model for my application

```
public class Object
{
    public List<Node> Nodes { get; set; }
}

public class Node
{
    public InstrumentData InstrumentData { get; set; }        
}

public class InstrumentData
{       
    public List<MySysData> MySysDataList { get; set; }
}

public class MySysData
{       
    public string SystemName { get; set; }        
}
```

Now I have Object list of nodes. I want to select not null "SystemName" from Object node list to a string list
I have tried following query but still its not has expected.

```
 var test = Object.Nodes.ToList<Node>()
  .Select(x => x.InstrumentData?.MySysDataList.ToList<MySysData>()
  .Select(y => y.SystemName)
  .ToList()) ;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need `Where`s and `SelectMany`:

```
List<string> sysNameList = Object.Nodes
   .Where(x => x.InstrumentData?.MySysDataList != null)
   .SelectMany(x => x.InstrumentData.MySysDataList
       .Select(y => y.SystemName)
       .Where(sName => sName != null))
   .ToList();
```

If you want to remove duplicates prepend `Distict` before the final `ToList`.

Comment: Upvoted this one due to better null checking rather than just returning nulls.  In reality this is what I would do even though I didn't put it in my answer.

Comment: This resolved null SystemName's but fail to push result into list "List<string> sysNameList"

Comment: @user7393522: Why? It selects all non-null `SysName`s(which is a string) and then calls `ToList` which will create a `List<string>`.

Comment: The non-generic type 'List' cannot be used with type arguments

Comment: Am accepting this answer because this has resolved my null values filtering. Thank you Tim.

Answer (score 0):

If you literally want just the system names, then because your internal select is returning a list (so the eventual output is a list of lists) you'll need to use `SelectMany` to 'flatten out' the list.  As long as things are enumerable you also don't need to repeatedly use `ToList()` all the time.  something like this ought to work I think:

```
var test = Object.Nodes
    .SelectMany(x => x.InstrumentData?.MySysDataList.Select(y => y.SystemName))
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Oh, by the way this won't remove any duplicates (where two different nodes have the same System Name in their list) or nulls (where a node has a null instrumentdata, or an instrumentdata has a null MySysDataList, or even a null system name).